# eslint no-restricted-imports, how do I make a rule that allows the import of a module in a specific way?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Is it possible using ESLINT to write a rule that allows you tyo enforce an import in a certain way, here's an example.

I want to enforce an import like this :-

```
import * as specificName from 'foo'
```

or

```
import * as anotherSpecific name from 'foo'
```

These should fail

```
import * as unspecificedName from 'foo'
import * as randomName from 'foo'
import random from 'foo'
```

I can stop specific imports but I want the **not** version so something like this:-

```
"no-restricted-imports": ["error", {
        "paths" : [{
            "name": "foo",
            "importNames": ["*"], ["not(specificName)"]
        }],
      }],
```

Comment: Looking through both the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-imports) and [source](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/main/lib/rules/no-restricted-imports.js) for the rule, I don't believe that any configuration options check against the _alias name_ of the import. The `importNames` option referenced in the question looks at the name of the thing being imported (always `"default"` in the examples above). Would you be interested in defining a custom rule (via an ESLint plugin) to accomplish the task?